# Eager load multiple relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to eager load multiple relationships in Laravel, but I can't find out how to do it. In Laravel Doc, it shows how to do it only for one relationship, like:

`$books = Book::with('author.contacts')->get();`

I need something like:

`$books = Book::with(array('author'=>array('contacts', 'groups', 'orders')))->get();`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$books = Book::with('author.contacts','author.groups', 'author.orders')->get();
```

Comment: Hi marcanuy. If you have that structure of relationship, and want to `sort` or `order` by `id` of `contracts`, how can we do that? while using eager loading.

Comment: Hi @Jonjie, it's been a while since this question, I can't answer that right now so I suggest you ask it as a new one.